# 1 node(s) had taint, that the pod didn't tolerate, 4 Insufficient CPUs

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, replicaset, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have a namespace HPA configuration as follows:-

`NAME   REFERENCE        TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE`

`web    Deployment/web   0%/65%    3         5         3          385d`

the namespace created 3 pods and then I invoked a deployment

for that new deployment, it started creating new pods but the pods are not able to be in a running state they

goes into CrashLoopBackOff state and the error is as follows

`1 node(s) had taint, that the pod didn't tolerate, 4 Insufficient CPUs.`

because it was a burning issue I deleted the deployment and started the new deployment from CI then it deleted the old pods and the new pods were recreated but it generated some downtime

I think there must be some other way to handle this or I have misconfigured the number of replicas and min/max pods

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question ?

Comment: hey @Chaitanya, thanks for responding, when I started a new deployment on that namespace at that moment it has 3 pods running, and when the deployment started the new pod got created but it went to CrashLoopBackOff because of insufficient CPUs I just wanted to know is my horizontalPodAutoscaler config is correct or I am missing on something.